# Android virtual device doesn't want to start with Arch Linux and Qt

Tags: android, qt, android-ndk, archlinux

I have installed Qt5 and created simple example app but the virtual machine shows error (from logcat):

```
D/StrictMode(  266): StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=96 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=2711 violation=2
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1074)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1557)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:354)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:291)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.query(TelephonyProvider.java:458)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:178)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:310)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmDataConnectionTracker.getPreferredApn(GsmDataConnectionTracker.java:2276)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmDataConnectionTracker.createAllApnList(GsmDataConnectionTracker.java:2112)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmDataConnectionTracker.onApnChanged(GsmDataConnectionTracker.java:1070)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmDataConnectionTracker.handleMessage(GsmDataConnectionTracker.java:2340)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
D/StrictMode(  266):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the issue?

Also can anyone recommend a list of possible things to configure or checklist:

- environment variables
- access rights

and so on.